# How to Blur certain parts or pages in a pdf while converting from google Slide with google Apps Script

Tags: pdf

I am generating a PDF using Google Apps Script and accessing a Google Slides presentation stored on my Google Drive. I want to blur, like use a gaussian filter for certain parts of the PDF with Google Apps Script before sending it to the customer.

I have researched extensively but have not found a solution. Can anyone help me with this issue? Thank you.

Comment: Do you just want the blurred appearance or do you really want to prevent retrieval of the blurred data?

Comment: Hey MKL, thank you very much for your response. Its not really needed to prevent a retrieval. As my costumers will not really have the technical abilities to do so.

Comment: *"As my costumers will not really have the technical abilities to do so"* - well, depending on how you implement the blurring, Ctrl-A + Ctrl-C may already suffice...